# C++ performance optimization for linear combination of large matrices?

Tags: c++, performance, multiplication, armadillo

I have a large tensor of floating point data with the dimensions `35k(rows) x 45(cols) x 150(slices)` which I have stored in an armadillo cube container. I need to linearly combine all the 150 slices together in under 35 ms (a must for my application). The linear combination floating point weights are also stored in an armadillo container. My fastest implementation so far takes 70 ms, averaged over a window of 30 frames, and I don't seem to be able to beat that. Please note I'm allowed **CPU** parallel computations but not GPU.

I have tried multiple different ways of performing this linear combination but the following code seems to be the fastest I can get (70 ms) as I believe I'm maximizing the cache hit chances by fetching the largest possible contiguous memory chunk at each iteration.

Please note that Armadillo stores data in **column major format**. So in a tensor, it first stores the columns of the first channel, then the columns of the second channel, then third and so forth.

```cpp
typedef std::chrono::system_clock Timer;
typedef std::chrono::duration<double> Duration;

int rows = 35000;
int cols = 45;
int slices = 150;
arma::fcube tensor(rows, cols, slices, arma::fill::randu);
arma::fvec w(slices, arma::fill::randu);

double overallTime = 0;
int window = 30;
for (int n = 0; n < window; n++) {

    Timer::time_point start = Timer::now();

    arma::fmat result(rows, cols, arma::fill::zeros);
    for (int i = 0; i < slices; i++)
        result += tensor.slice(i) * w(i);

    Timer::time_point end = Timer::now();
    Duration span = end - start;
    double t = span.count();
    overallTime += t;
    cout << "n = " << n << " --> t = " << t * 1000.0 << " ms" << endl;
}

cout << endl << "average time = " << overallTime * 1000.0 / window << " ms" << endl;
```

I need to optimize this code by **at least 2x** and I would very much appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: Partially unrolling the inner loop may help. If `slices` is divisible by 4, the unrolling would conceptually be: `for ( int i = 0; i < slices; i+=4 )  { result += (tensor.slice(i) * w(i)) +  (tensor.slice(i+1) * w(i+1)) + (tensor.slice(i+2) * w(i+2)) + (tensor.slice(i+3) * w(i+3));`.  Note the `i+=4` in the loop definition. To finalize the calculation, any leftover slices (last 2 in this case) would need to be taken care of after the loop.

Comment: Also enable SIMD auto-vectorization in Armadillo, by using the `-O3` switch in gcc and clang.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. It brought the computation time from 70 ms down to 45 ms. I will post it as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @hbrerkere suggested in the comment section, by using the `-O3` flag and making the following changes, the performance improved by almost 65%. The code now runs at **45 ms** as opposed to the initial 70 ms.

```cpp
int lastStep = (slices / 4 - 1) * 4;
int i = 0;
while (i <= lastStep) {
    result += tensor.slice(i) * w_id(i) + tensor.slice(i + 1) * w_id(i + 1) + tensor.slice(i + 2) * w_id(i + 2) + tensor.slice(i + 3) * w_id(i + 3);
    i += 4;
}
while (i < slices) {
    result += tensor.slice(i) * w_id(i);
    i++;
}
```

Comment: This may go even faster if the loop is unrolled further. The optimal amount of unroll is dependent on the cache size, CPU, etc.

Answer (score 2):

First at all I need to admit, I'm not familiar with the `arma` framework or the memory layout; the least if the syntax `result += slice(i) * weight` evaluates lazily.

Two primary problem and its solution anyway lies in the memory layout and the memory-to-arithmetic computation ratio.

To say `a+=b*c` is problematic because it needs to read the `b` and `a`, write `a` and uses up to two arithmetic operations (two, if the architecture does not combine multiplication and accumulation).

If the memory layout is of form `float tensor[rows][columns][channels]`, the problem is converted to making `rows * columns` dot products of length `channels` and should be expressed as such.

If it's `float tensor[c][h][w]`, it's better to unroll the loop to `result+= slice(i) + slice(i+1)+...`. Reading four slices at a time reduces the memory transfers by 50%.

It might even be better to process the results in chunks of 4*N results (reading from all the 150 channels/slices) where N<16, so that the accumulators can be allocated explicitly or implicitly by the compiler to SIMD registers.

There's a possibility of a minor improvement by padding the slice count to multiples of 4 or 8, by compiling with `-ffast-math` to enable fused multiply accumulate (if available) and with multithreading.

The constraints indicate the need to perform 13.5GFlops, which is a reasonable number in terms of arithmetic (for many modern architectures)  but also it means at least 54 Gb/s memory bandwidth, which could be relaxed with fp16 or 16-bit fixed point arithmetic.

**EDIT**

Knowing the memory order to be `float tensor[150][45][35000]` or `float tensor[kSlices][kRows * kCols == kCols * kRows]` suggests to me to try first unrolling the outer loop by 4 (or maybe even 5, as 150 is not divisible by 4 requiring special case for the excess) streams.

```
void blend(int kCols, int kRows, float const *tensor, float *result, float const *w) {
    // ensure that the cols*rows is a multiple of 4 (pad if necessary)
    // - allows the auto vectorizer to skip handling the 'excess' code where the data
    //   length mod simd width != 0
    // one could try even SIMD width of 16*4, as clang 14
    // can further unroll the inner loop to 4 ymm registers
    auto const stride = (kCols * kRows + 3) & ~3;
    // try also s+=6, s+=3, or s+=4, which would require a dedicated inner loop (for s+=2)
    for (int s = 0; s < 150; s+=5) {
        auto src0 = tensor  + s * stride;
        auto src1 = src0 + stride;
        auto src2 = src1 + stride;
        auto src3 = src2 + stride;
        auto src4 = src3 + stride;
        auto dst = result;
        for (int x = 0; x < stride; x++) {
            // clang should be able to optimize caching the weights
            // to registers outside the innerloop
            auto add = src0[x] * w[s] +
                       src1[x] * w[s+1] +
                       src2[x] * w[s+2] +
                       src3[x] * w[s+3] +
                       src4[x] * w[s+4];
            // clang should be able to optimize this comparison
            // out of the loop, generating two inner kernels
            if (s == 0) {
                dst[x] = add;
            } else {
                dst[x] += add;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT 2**

Another starting point (before adding multithreading) would be consider changing the layout to

```
float tensor[kCols][kRows][kSlices + kPadding]; // padding is optional
```

The downside now is that `kSlices = 150` can't anymore fit all the weights in registers (and secondly kSlices is not a multiple of 4 or 8). Furthermore the final reduction needs to be horizontal.

The upside is that reduction no longer needs to go through memory, which is a big thing with the added multithreading.

```
void blendHWC(float const *tensor, float const *w, float *dst, int n, int c) {
     // each thread will read from 4 positions in order
     // to share the weights -- finding the best distance
     // might need some iterations
     auto src0 = tensor;
     auto src1 = src0 + c;
     auto src2 = src1 + c;
     auto src3 = src2 + c; 
     for (int i = 0; i < n/4; i++) {
         vec8 acc0(0.0f), acc1(0.0f), acc2(0.0f), acc3(0.0f);
         // #pragma unroll?
         for (auto j = 0; j < c / 8; c++) {
             vec8 w(w + j);
             acc0 += w * vec8(src0 + j);
             acc1 += w * vec8(src1 + j);
             acc2 += w * vec8(src2 + j);
             acc3 += w * vec8(src3 + j);
         }
         vec4 sum = horizontal_reduct(acc0,acc1,acc2,acc3);
         sum.store(dst); dst+=4;
     } 
}
```

These `vec4` and `vec8` are some custom SIMD classes, which map to SIMD instructions either through intrinsics, or by virtue of the compiler being able to do compile `using vec4 = float __attribute__ __attribute__((vector_size(16)));` to efficient SIMD code.

Comment: Thanks for the response. `cols*rows` is already a multiple of 4 and I tried `s+=3`, `s+=5`, and `s+=6`  but didn't try `s+=4` because 4 isn't a factor of 150 and it would crash. The computation time would fluctuate between 80-90 ms. which is around 10-15 ms slower than what Armadillo does. Armadillo seems to be super optimized already :( I may have to find a mathematical approximation leading to almost the same result with engaging only 75 representative channels instead of the entire 150 channels.

Comment: Good to know. Do you know if Armadillo uses multithreading? I would expect it to do it, since what I can deduct from the syntax `result += slice(i) * w` should be inferior to reading from multiple rows -- _unless_ the product cols*rows happens to be a bad multiple of a power of two, in which case those input streams would compete from the same cache lines way too often.

Also I guess you have compiled with `-ffast-math -march=native -O3`

Comment: Yes, based on the **Speed** section on the Armadillo website http://arma.sourceforge.net/faq.html , it uses multi-threading if linked to OpenBlas which is the case in my project. I also did activate those flags in my `CMakeList.txt` but the speed did not change much. `set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-ffast-math -march=native -O3")`

Comment: I would guess, that's what you need to add then as well -- probably the best is to split the 45*35000 dimension among all the threads, since splitting the 150 channel dimension requires a final reduction (addition).

Comment: Thanks for the second edit. Unfortunately, the tensor format of `tensor[channels][cols][rows]` is preset, and if I reorder it, it requires huge memory allocation and copying which will be slow. I also tried multi-threading and thread pooling but I wasn't able to implement them properly as I'm not an expert.

Answer (score 0):

Without having the actual code, I'm guessing that

```
+= tensor.slice(i) * w_id(i)
```

creates a temporary object and then adds it to the lhs. Yes, overloaded operators look nice, but I would write a function

addto( lhs, slice1, w1, slice2, w2, ....unroll to 4... )

which translates to pure loops over the elements:

```
for (i=....)
  for (j=...)
    lhs[i][j] += slice1[i][j]*w1[j] + slice2[i][j] &c
```

It would surprise me if that doesn't buy you an extra factor.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Unfortunately, I didn't fully understand how to avoid the temporary object creation as the result of say `slice(i) * w(i)` should be stored somewhere prior to addition anyway, shouldn't it? Would you mind explaining more? I would appreciate a code example, if possible.

Comment: @Davar I've added some code. For efficiency, you need to completely give up on temporary objects. I think. I haven't tested this.

Comment: Looking at the Armadillo source code, there is an elaborate expression template mechanism to process `+=`. No temporary matrices, cubes or slices are generated.

Comment: @hbrerkere Interesting. Then the question is whether the compiler understands that templating stuff well enough to generate vector instructions.

Comment: @VictorEijkhout I tried that by writing the `addTo(result, s0, w0,...)` function and passing the lhs and slices by reference. I then wrote two for loops, with the inner one iterating through the rows because Armadillo stores data in column major format. `result(i, j) += s0(i, j) * w0 + s1(i, j) * w1 + s2(i, j) * w2 + s3(i, j) * w3;`  The computation time went up to 200 ms and I'm suspecting it's significantly slower because the `*` operator in Armadillo invokes parallel multiplication using OpenBlas.

Comment: @Davar Ok, that's too many details that were unknown to me.